# A power series involving binomial coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I've been playing around with infinite sums for quite a while now, but recently, I've come across the following question in an Under-Graduate Mathematics Book that is specifically targeted at problem solving. The problem is as follows,

Evaluate the following:
$$\sum_{r=2}^\infty \Biggl(\binom{2r}{r}{\biggl(\frac{x}{4}\biggr)^r}\Biggr)^2$$

where x is strictly less than unity.

I've thoroughly checked that the sum is, in fact, convergent, however, I am completely stumped as to how I am to evaluate it. I am guessing that the final expression is one involving the variable 'x' since I do not see any way for it to be eliminated somehow. Any kind of hint/solution/explanation to the problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, Robert Z, I have checked and rechecked the problem but I can affirmatively say that it isn't the summation that is being squared but the term of summation.

Comment: I, see. Just a curiosity, what is the title of this Under-Graduate Mathematics Book?

Comment: "where x is strictly less than unity." what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @zhw. Taken literally, it means $x<1$. I go so far as to guess is actually means $|x|<1$.

Comment: We have

$$\sum_{r=2}^N\,{\Biggl(\binom{2r}{r}\,y^r\Biggr)}^2=
{\Biggl(\sum_{r=2}^N\,\binom{2r}{r}y^r\Biggr)}^2-2\sum_{r=2}^{N-1}\sum_{s=r+1}^N\binom{2r}{r}\binom{2s}{s}y^{r+s}$$

The first term is just a partial sum of the ordinary generating function of the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).
If one could simplify the other term, that might lead to an answer.

$$\sum_{r=2}^{N-1}\sum_{s=r+1}^N\binom{2r}{r}\binom{2s}{s}y^{r+s}=\sum_{j=5}^{N(N-1)}y^j\Bigg[\sum_{2\leq a<\lfloor j/2\rfloor}\binom{2a}{a}\binom{2(j-a)}{j-a}\Biggl]$$

Comment: Solution $\frac{2 K\left(x^2\right)}{\pi }-\frac{x^2}{4}-1$           where $K$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind. Without the square the solution is much nicer $\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{1-x}-1-\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: @Raffaele: Post an answer instead of comment?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple.

First, consider the full series:

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^2 \frac{x^{2n}}{4^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!^2}{n!^4} \frac{x^{2n}}{4^{2n}}$$

Consider the ratio of general terms:

$$\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}=\frac{(2n+2)^2(2n+1)^2}{16(n+1)^4} x^2=\frac{(n+1/2)^2}{(n+1)^2} x^2=\frac{(n+1/2)^2}{(n+1)} \frac{x^2}{n+1}$$

$$T_0=1$$

By definition:

$$S(x)={_2 F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,x^2 \right)$$

Using the integral representation of the hypergeometric function:

$${_2 F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,x^2 \right)=\frac{1}{B \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \int_0^1 t^{-1/2} (1-t)^{-1/2} (1-x^2 t)^{-1/2} dt=$$

We know $B \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \pi$. Let's introduce a new variable $t=y^2$, then:

$$=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-x^2 y^2)}}$$

But this is just the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

So:

$$S(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}  K(x^2)$$

And, subtracting the two first terms, we get for the original series:

> $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}^2 \frac{x^{2n}}{4^{2n}}=\frac{2}{\pi}  K(x^2)-1-\frac{x^2}{4}$$

Just as Raffaele pointed out in the comments.

Comment: what is $K$ here ?

Comment: @M.A.Sarkar, complete elliptic integral with Mathematica argument convention. I think

Comment: Can you guess similar treatment as above for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{2n}{n}x^n$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}x^n$ ?